# Ubuntu 16.04 freezing when I power off external hard disk

Tags: mount

Whenever I try to safely power off my HDD, it completely freezes and CTRL+ALT+F1 also doesn't work.

Edit from comment:

I click on the "Power Off disk" button. Everything freezes after that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gDxv.jpg

Comment: How do you "safely power off your HDD"? What happens when you do?

Comment: I click on the "Power Off disk" button. Everything freezes after that.  https://imgur.com/a/jFPinoq

Answer (score 1):

You must `umount` the disk first, so Ubuntu has a chance to finish writing the data that's buffered in RAM. Either use the `umount` command, or Right-Mouse-Button hold on the disk's icon, and select "Eject". What you're doing (powering off the disk while Ubuntu has it mounted) confuses the system.

Comment: Tried both. Don't work at all. System freezing regardless. ALT+SysRq+REISUB also doesn't work.